# How to speedup s3 bucket object filter

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using the following python code to filter required prefix and pattern, but due to the volume of files in the bucket, its taking too long to display the results and web server is timing out, there is any way i can speedup the process

```
my_list = []
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
for line in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path):
     if re.search(SourceFilePattern, line.key):
          my_list.append(line.key)
```

Comment: How many objects are there in the bucket and within that particular prefix? Have you tried using a `client` method instead of a `resource` method to see whether it is faster?

Comment: Hi John, there are around 485319 objects in the bucket and search is taking around 5 mins, this number will gradually increase and as per my understanding client is used mostly when we know the exact file name but here we are using pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to periodically create static CSV-like file with object metadata and then run your code against it. It will be faster than waiting for network I/O for each call.

If you want to process it real-time-ish and give responses from webserver, I'd rather populate some sort of DynamoDB table beforehand and query it from webserver process. You can react to S3 Put events and trigger lambda which will put data into DynamoDB if file matches the criteria.